# Truth of an inequality involving differentials

Tags: calculus, inequality, derivatives

Is the following inequality true?

$$
s\frac{\partial \frac{\partial f(s,t)}{\partial s}}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial f(s,t)}{\partial t}>0
$$

Given that $f(s,t)$ is a monotonically-decreasing function of $t$ and $f(s,t)\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$, and a monotonically-increasing function of $s$ and $f(s,t)\to c$ as $s \to \infty$, where $c$ is a positive constant, and $s>0$ and $t>0$ and $f(s,t)>0$.

If this is not always true, then is it possible to say something about when it is not true?

Comment: what does "diminishing returns" mean?

Comment: Meaning that the function asymptotes, or that the rate of change asymptotes towards zero.

Comment: I dont get it. How can $f(\cdot,t)$ be monotonically increasing as a function of $s$ yet still satisfy $\lim_{s \to \infty} f(s,t) = 0$?

Comment: $lim_{s->\infty}f(s,t)=c$, some positive constant, but the rate of change wrt $s$ tends to zero. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, okay. And I guess with rate of change you mean the partial derivative with respect to $s$.

Comment: Yes, that's right.